# jquery animate with translate y and fadeIn

Tags: jquery, css

put within hover event

```
$('.text-warning').css('opacity',1);
$('.text-warning').css('transition','opacity 0.2s ease-out');
$('.text-warning').css('transform','translateY(20px)');
```

Initially I set the element to opacity zero, and I thought it could do the fadeIn and translate effect? but it doesn't work, it appear just like that, it wasn't slide down or fade..

Answer (score 3):

For the next guy that finds this post ... an ANSWER using CSS!

First - as noted above the .css methods described above won't work - forget it and don't waste your time.
 Next - create a class that describes the animation properties you want to add.   Place it in your CSS file.

```
.text-warning-anim {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(20px);
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out, transform 0.2s;
}
```

Now - when the event fires, use addClass() to add this class to your object.  It will animate.  This works with keyframes as well.  I'm new to jQuery, but this works for me (tested, using it heavily).  In your example, something like this:

```
$(".text-warning").hover (
    function() {
        $(this).addClass("text-warning-anim");
    },
    function() {
        $(this).removeClass("text-warning-anim");
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this !

```
$( ".text-warning" ).animate({
    opacity: 1,
    transition: "opacity 0.2s ease-out",
    transform: "translateY(20px)"
}, 1500 );
```

Comment: you need to add `, transform 0.2s` to the transition attribute. The animation needs to know how long it's duration is and it has to be typed explicitly. There also needs to be a comma between animation declarations. ;)

Answer (score -2):

`.css()` is not intended for animated transitions. The function you are looking for is `.animate()`.

http://jsfiddle.net/LimitedWard/U4JZ6/1/

```
$('.text-warning').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).animate({
            ...
        });
    },
    function() {
        $(this).animate({
            ...
        });
    }
);
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: I believe the questioner wants to leverage CSS3 transitions, not JS-based animations.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That was not made clear by the original question. He posed the question in the context of jQuery animations and hover events, so I gave him a solution using jQuery. I agree, though, that it would be better to use CSS3 transitions.

Comment: @user3836151 I know that the `.css()` function supports CSS3. The problem is that it doesn't support transitions or animations. The whole point of the `.animate()` function is to "tween" CSS properties over a period of time. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LimitedWard/U4JZ6/1/